# Ler txt com números e criar um dicionário em Python

Tags: python, dicionário

Boa tarde Estou tentando criar um Grafo a partir de um arquivo Txt porem no dicionário gerado os números estão saindo como se fossem strings alguém pode me ajudar , segue o código :
Arquivo txt

```
`
0   1
1   2
1   4
1   5
2   3
2   6
3   2
3   7
4   5
4   0
5   6
6   5
6   7`

with open("/Users/jonnathanvinicius/Desktop/Trabalho PAA/cormen.txt","r") as f:    
G={}

    for line in f:
        u, v = line.split()
        if u not in G:
            G[u] = [v]
        else:
            G[u].append(v)
print "O Grafo Web-NotreDame foi Criado"
```

saida do print `{'1': ['2', '4', '5'], '0': ['1'], '3': ['2', '7'], '2': ['3', '6'], '5': ['6'], '4': ['5', '0'], '6': ['5', '7']}`

Answer (score 1):

Basta converter os caracteres para números inteiros.

```py
u, v = map(int, line.split())
```

Alterando essa linha, resulta em

```
{0: [1], 1: [2, 4, 5], 2: [3, 6], 3: [2, 7], 4: [5, 0], 5: [6], 6: [5, 7]}
```